# What is the conjugate transpose of $|0\rangle_{A}|1\rangle_{B}$?

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose a composite state is in $|0\rangle_{A}|1\rangle_{B}$. Then their conjugate transpose would be
$\langle 0|_{A}\langle 1|_{B}$?

Note: Why this question? Because I was checking MIT's "Quantum Information Science's 2010 class's homework solution of 3" ([link](http://web.mit.edu/2.111/www/2010/ps3_2010Sol2.pdf)) Page 2

[image]

Here is the corresponding problem set.(In case you feel curious) ([link](http://web.mit.edu/2.111/www/2010/ps3_2010d.pdf))

Comment: Yes, that's just a typo.

Comment: @Rammus Can we believe it? It's MIT and they are giving us typo.With big names come big responsibilities. They are publishing it to the whole world and they didn't check it? It made me super confused.

Comment: Yes, you can check a document and still very easily miss typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the conjugate is $\langle 0|_A\langle 1|_B$. This is also other times written as $\langle 0_A|\langle 1_B|$, or $\langle 0_A|\otimes \langle 1_B|$, or just $\langle 01|$, or similar ways. These are all just notational differences. They are all equivalent as long as one knows what is being discussed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming..+1